# What does "=> Type" mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, function

Looking at akka's source I faced the following construction:

```
def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](creator: ⇒ T): Props
```

I was confused by the `creator: ⇒ T` parameter declaration. So, trying it myself

```
class TestFunction {
  def test(foo: => Int) = {
    println(foo.getClass)
    println(foo)
  }
}

val testFoo = TestFunction()
testFoo.test(10)
```

I got the following result:

```
int
10
```

And it works ***completely the same*** as if it would be declared just as `def test(foo: Int)`. What does `=>` stand for in the parameter declaration?

Comment: Use http://symbolhound.com/ for weird-looking method names.

Comment: Basically, => means "call by name". If you don't include the =>, it defaults to call by value. It would have been hard to realize this question was a duplicate since you didn't know the term "call by name".